# Renaming file with PHP

Tags: php, replace, file-handling

I am using code that i found on here which works great but the moment i try to access a file in a sub-directory it just doesn't want to work.

It gets a file, creates a temp file to write to, then looks for some text in the file and replaces that text with new text, then saves the updated file, then deletes the temp file.

The below works fine:

```
        $reading = fopen('links.htm', 'r');
        $writing = fopen('links.tmp', 'w+');

        $replaced = false;

        while (!feof($reading)) {
          $line = fgets($reading);
          if (stristr($line,'::template::')) {
            $line = "replacement line!\n";
            $replaced = true;
          }
          fputs($writing, $line);
        }
        fclose($reading); fclose($writing);
        // might as well not overwrite the file if we didn't replace anything
        if ($replaced) 
        {
          rename('links.tmp', 'links.htm');
        } else {
          unlink('links.tmp');
        }
```

This doesnt work:

```
        $reading = fopen('path/to/links.htm', 'r');
        $writing = fopen('path/to/links.tmp', 'w+');

        $replaced = false;

        while (!feof($reading)) {
          $line = fgets($reading);
          if (stristr($line,'::template::')) {
            $line = "replacement line!\n";
            $replaced = true;
          }
          fputs($writing, $line);
        }
        fclose($reading); fclose($writing);
        // might as well not overwrite the file if we didn't replace anything
        if ($replaced) 
        {
          rename('path/to/links.tmp', 'path/to/links.htm');
        } else {
          unlink('path/to/links.tmp');
        }
```

Any suggestions?

The `path` is absolute i defined it in the code earlier and use it to create file and write files to but when i want the code above to work in the same way it just doesn't want to.

Also the folders permissions has been set to write and read which also works fine.

Ran the code in the sub folder and works fine but not from the top level directory.

Error reporting is turned off, turned it on now:

> > The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (code: 32)

Comment: Does it work if you try opendir (http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) on the folder "path/to"? Maybe you don't have the required access.

Comment: yes its probably just a wrong path issue

Comment: It reads the path fine and displays all the files in the path fine. So thats not working.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not an error message. What happens? Do you get an error? Is error reporting enabled? Have you checked the permissions?

Comment: Meaning the directory has write enabled. And is writing files to it as it should, except the code above that i stated is not working when it has to write to a sub directory. I tested it in the directory it has to write to and it worked fine as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a week of looking around, testing, breaking and recoding a lot i found a simple way to do this.

Since most of the content is dynamically created as well as the links.htm file, it was quite hard finding where and when the file is accessed since the code accesses about 300 of my clients sites and updates the links file.

Simple fix:

```
$path = "path/on/server/";

$conn_id = ftp_connect("ftp.testftp.com") or die("Could not connect");
ftp_login($conn_id,"admin","ert456");

$old_file = $path.'links.htm';
$new_file = $path.'_template.htm';
ftp_rename($conn_id, $old_file, $new_file);

$source = fopen($new_file, "w");
$localTarget = "path/to/links.htm";

ftp_fget($conn,$source,$localTarget,FTP_ASCII);

    $reading = fopen('path/to/links.htm', 'r');
    $writing = fopen('path/to/_template.htm', 'w+');

    $replaced = false;

    while (!feof($reading)) {
      $line = fgets($reading);
      if (stristr($line,'::template::')) {
        $line = "replacement line!\n";
        $replaced = true;
      }
      fputs($writing, $line);
    }
    fclose($reading); fclose($writing);
    // might as well not overwrite the file if we didn't replace anything
    if ($replaced) 
    {
      rename('path/to/_template.htm', 'path/to/links.htm');
    } else {
      unlink('path/to/_template.htm');
    }

 $local_file = "path/to/links.htm";

 ftp_put($conn_id, $path, $local_file, FTP_BINARY);

 ftp_close($conn_id);
```

There is probably easier ways to do this but this is what worked for me, hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

PHP will need to have write permissions to that directory in order to write to it.  It may be that it has write permissions to the current directory `.`, but does not have permissions to write to the subdirectory `./path/to/`.

**Edit:** If you get a PHP error, you should include it in your question.

**Edit after OP Edit:**

That error means that something currently has `links.htm` opened.  I see that you're `fclose()`ing the file before renaming it, so my guess is that you probably have `links.htm` open in some other application (e.g. browser or text editor).

**Edit #3:**

If you do not have one of the `links.htm` or `links.tmp` files open in another application, it could be that you're using Windows - in which case the `rename()` call will execute before the `fclose()` even though it comes after it in the code.  The solution to this is to add a `sleep()` call after closing the handle:

```
fclose($reading); fclose($writing);
sleep(1); // this should allow the handle to be properly closed before the rename() call
```

Comment: Error reporting is turned off at the moment. Tested it by writing a file to it and `unlink()` works fine from the current directory. Tested the code in the directory and works fine as well.

Comment: @JohanPretorius:  I suggest you turn error reporting on for this script so you can see what's going wrong.  Otherwise, it's going to be very difficult for you to find the problem.

Comment: @JohanPretorius:  If you didn't have one of the files open, it may have been a timing issue.  See my edit.

Comment: Tried both ways now and getting error: Access is denied. (code: 5) even set the file permissions again as well. Using WAMP.

Comment: @JohanPretorius: "Access is denied" is definitely a permissions issue.  You'll need to make sure that PHP has write permissions for both directories.  That means you'll have to set the permissions *for the user that Apache is running as*, not your own user.

Comment: Thank you. Ill give that a try now and see what happens. I am thinking that i might have a loop somewhere that is accessing the file more than once when creating the directory for the file to be placed in.

Comment: "it could be that you're using Windows - in which case the rename() call will execute before the fclose() even though it comes after it in the code" @drrcknlsn what is the source for this information?